# Send an email using text fields for the subject and body instead of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send an email within my app, but without the standard email layout from apple's mail app, which could be obtained through MFMailComposeViewController. I would like to have two text fields, one for the users email, one for the body, and a button to send the email. Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In general, Apple does not approve of sending email other than via MFMailComposeViewController & associated user interactions.  This is to protect users from an app that secretly sends emails without their knowledge.  You can, of course, "prime" the email message with your text.

Comment: you cannot, but you can use your external email server, and you can reach it in background from your app via any common protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `MFMailComposeViewController` is that it looks and acts the same as the system standard e-mail application, also after iOS itself changes (think iOS 6 --> iOS 7). This is primarily for user convenience, so you're supposed to use it. AFAIK, you don't get direct access to the e-mail protocol stack anyway, but then again, you don't need to worry about it.

Of course, you can set the subject and body programmatically, so if you really wanted to, you could have those two text fields, and then copy whatever the user has entered, to use it with `MFMailComposeViewController`, but why bother? It makes the user experience worse, and it's extra work for you.